# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://serverfault.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: It says that there are three moderator positions to be filled. Which three seats are being contested? Are we increasing the number of moderators from 5 to 8? Are some of the current moderators stepping down? If so, which ones?